# wire frame modifier is not working, mesh shows solid in wire frame mode

Tags: wireframe

i have been following chair tutorial of blender guru, i followed all steps correctly, but when he turned on his wire frame mode, his mesh turned into a piece of wires same shape as mesh but when i did the same my mesh turned black and remained solid. can any one please tell me what have i done wrong[image: image in the second image i have turned on x-in the third pic i have only turned on wire frame mode and it has turned my into something weirdray mode and wire frame mode but still it does not look like thisof mesh in wire frame mode from the tutorial i am following]

Comment: Hello could you please show a screenshot?

Comment: Please add a screenshot of your own Blender window to compare against Andrew's one in the tutorial. Window > Save Screenshot  menu in Blender.